# Partial correlation with random effects

Tags: r, correlation, mixed-model, partial-correlation

Partial correlation analysis allows one to assess the correlation between a dependent variable and an independent variable given a set of covariates.

Some pairs of observations in my data are related and therefore not independent.

Normally, I would model this using linear mixed models with random intercepts for the group variable (in `R`: `lmer(y~x + z + (1|group), data=data)`), however, I'm not sure how to do a similar thing for partial correlations.

Does such a thing exist?

If not, can I get the correlation between my dependent and independent variables of interest using the information provided after fitting a linear mixed model?

Answers with suggestions in `R` would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are thinking about?

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand Do you mean what I'd like to have done or are you requesting more specifics about the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial correlation is essentially the Pearson correlation between the residuals of both variables regressed onto the covariates, see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation#Using_linear_regression).

While I don't know if it's *valid* to extend that to mixed models (I don't have a reason to assume it's not), it is technically quite straightforward:

```
# Partial correlation between Y1 and Y2 controlling for X and R
fit1 <- lme4::lmer(Y1 ~ X + (1|R))
fit2 <- lme4::lmer(Y2 ~ X + (1|R))
cor(residuals(fit1), residuals(fit2))
```

I might also suggest having a look at the [partR2](https://cran.r-project.org/package=partR2) package.

Comment: And so in this example `fit1` is a regression of the variable of interest as the dependent, `X`as the multiple covariates, and `(1|R)` the group, fit2 is the same but with my actual outcome of interest, and then we are simply checking the correlation between the residuals since the residuals are now uncorrelated with the covariates, so any remaining correlation is "true" correlation between `y` and my variable of interest. Have I understood correctly?

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct.